# How to install 32 bit app by homebrew

Tags: homebrew, 32-bit

I want to install 32 bit gettext by homebrew:

```
brew install gettext --32-bit
```

But when it is still x86_64 version:

```
file /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.2/lib/libgettextlib-0.18.2.dylib 

/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.2/lib/libgettextlib-0.18.2.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You probably want to use `brew install gettext --universal`, which will build a universal ("fat") binary containing both 32-bit and 64-bit code.  There's no `--32-bit` option; see `brew info gettext` to see what options are supported.

```
$ brew install gettext --universal
[...snip...]
$ file /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.2/lib/libgettextlib-0.18.2.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.2/lib/libgettextlib-0.18.2.dylib: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.2/lib/libgettextlib-0.18.2.dylib (for architecture i386):    Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.2/lib/libgettextlib-0.18.2.dylib (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

Comment: `--universal` option is no longer supported on homebrew. alas.